# Wrong ownership when SFTP files

Tags: sftp, sshd, chroot-jail

I have successfully setup jailed SFTP access using ChrootDirectory.

```
Match Group sftponly
     ChrootDirectory %h
     X11Forwarding no
     AllowTCPForwarding no
     ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I also used: `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0002` to ensure proper permissions are applied.

My issue now is when new files or folders are SFTPed to the server, or created using the SFTP client, they are assigned to the user and the group is the user instead of apache.

How can I make it so that my files will automatically be assigned to the apache group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the primary group of your user accordingly: `usermod -g apache your_SFTP_Username`

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had this already but apparently I removed it from my script.